# How to pass a variable from a link to a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, argument-passing

I would like a jQuery function to know which link was clicked to call it, i.e. I would like the link's id value to be passed to the jQuery function.

Is this possible? If so what is the neatest way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Inside the [`click()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click) event handler you can refer to the element clicked by `this`.

```
$("a").click(function() {
  alert(this.id);
  ...
});
```

or

```
$("a").click(function() {
  alert($(this).attr("id"));
  ...
});
```

Comment: THanks .... I really need to remember the "this.id" technique.It basically solves all the jQuery questions I keep asking.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a").click(function() { 
   var linkid = $(this).attr("id");

   // use linkId here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to cancel default behaviour, or you won't achieve nothing.

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var linkid = $(this).attr("id");
   //do whatever here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").click(function() {
  alert($(this).attr("id"));
  ...
});
```

i can say this same..